# Disabling TRACE in Visual Studio for .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have recently decided to migrate my project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6. During this conversion process I have hit a snag that leaves me stumped.

In .NET Framework 4.8, you have two checkboxes which say "Define TRACE constant" and "Define DEBUG constant". You can turn these off during a build to prevent `TRACE` and `DEBUG` from being defined when running the "Debug configuration" or the "Release configuration". This works great.

However in .NET 6 (in Visual Studio 2022) for some reason, this functionality has been removed. You can no longer untick these boxes OR remove these symbols. VB, F# and ASP.NET still have these options.

It is possible to remove the `DEBUG` symbol by using the rather obscure `DisableImplicitConfigurationDefines` tag in the XML root or by creating a new configuration and basing it on nothing. But a problem poses itself for the `TRACE` constant. This does not seem possible to remove at all, there is no XML tag given and you can't can't get rid off it by creating a new config.

I am not 100% certain but I get the impression from browsing through the .net source code that some genius decided to hard code this and now they don't want to fix it because it would be "a breaking change". They did add a `DisableDiagnosticTracing` XML toggle but this does not show in the UI and having to manually edit a file when I want to change this seems really annoying.

I am aware you can override this annoying behaviour with a switch when compiling it yourself from the command line but this is not practical since I have this library as a project next to my main project and I often make changes in both. Is there anyway that removes the `TRACE` constant? I did try to use some "Replace" command I believe but then I can not change any of the other `DEBUG` toggles (they just get grayed out and put as text instead of checkboxes). I assume VS borks out when you mess with `$(DefineConstants)` in the XML file.

Does anybody know any practical way to solve this problem?

Any suggestions are appreciated and welcome!

Some pictures to clarify (before)

[image: Old debug constants]

After (new)

[image: New debug constants]

Comment: It seems that you already use Trace constants in your project and you don't want to delete them. If so, you have to use what you call "very annoying methods" to disable them. I found a post in github https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11530

Comment: Hello, thank for your feedback and I appreciate what you made and what you do but this is not an acceptable solution for my workflow. As such I am looking for an alternative. If none is provided or it's not possible I'm afraid I will not be able to migrate. I'm very disappointed how this decision was made without giving any thought for people coming from alternative Microsoft solutions and telling them "to suck it up".

Comment: Hi, you can go to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home) to report this issue so that you can get more valuable help.

Comment: Hey, you're totally right. I posted a comment over at the Visual Studio Developer website. In the mean time I'll leave this post up in case somebody has found a practical solution. I hope I can resolve it one way or another, until then I'll have to wait with the migration.

Comment: Hello, would you like to ask if there is any progress on your issue in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home). You can share the post about "Disabling TRACE" in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home) so that it can help more people